# Is there more than one instance of the Empty Set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

It seems any additional instance would be equivalent in every respect to the first, hence indistinguishable, and arguably identical.

I.e., there is only one Empty Set.  Correct?

Comment: Two sets, $A,B$, are equal, iff: $\forall x(x\in A\iff x\in B)$. So there is only one empty set.

Comment: If two, then every element of the one is an element of the other, and conversely. Thus the two are one. (They’re not even *arguably* identical.)

Comment: Closely related: [Why there is a unique empty set?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/987545/why-there-is-a-unique-empty-set)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the most popular version of axiomatic set theory, ZF, there is an axiom, the *Axiom of Extensionality,* which says if two sets have the same elements they are equal.

However, there are non-extensional set theories. These are much more a minority taste. You will find some information under **urelemente**.

Comment: I've encountered set theories with urelements before, but usually the urelements themselves are not considered sets; and in the only exception I'm aware of, the urelements are never *empty* sets, but rather, are singleton sets containing themselves. Are you saying that there are set theories where urelements can be empty sets?

Answer (score 3):

A set is defined by the elements it contains.  The empty set contains no elements.  A putative second empty set would contain the same elements, namely none, hence is equal to the empty set.